# change colors for each kind of python variable in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I override my VS Code Appearance configuration to change the color of each type of python variable ? For example:

[image]

Comment: that is a semantic syntax coloring, TextMate scopes do not contain type of variables

Comment: if the name of the variable is not enough to know what it is, change the name